# Checking for changes after clicking element that redirects to a new page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chrome

Browser: Chrome

I am testing that when you click on a button, it becomes disabled (account selection). However, my check does not get executed until after the new page loads. I assume this is part of the browser's behavior.
I've tried using execute script but that didn't change much.

Am I crazy?

Comment: I found a resolution for the time being which uses all javascript. It clicks the link and returns the state of the class list. This works for my uses, but I feel it's dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default focus will change newly opened window , so change your focus to old window

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

// Perform the actions to.open new tab

// Switch back to original browser (first window)
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

If it's opens in same tab,

Then

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

try {
  driver.get("http://url/to/my/slow/loading/page");
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
  // Ignore the exception.
}
```

//Validate , and set pageloadtimeout to normal which is 15 mins
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(900, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Also try [Page loading strategy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/).

Comment: It is not opening a new tab, same tab. I use this method for other stuff though.

Comment: I found a resolution for the time being which uses all javascript. It clicks the link and returns the state of the class list. This works for my uses, but I feel it's dirty.

Comment: You can reset the pagetimeout and then set it back

Comment: I can't use page load strategy, as setting to none would involve a lot of fixes. this is a single set of tests, so not worth rewriting. ill post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked best for my situation was to click the element then return the new state.
This may not work for your case, PDHide suggested a few good solutions.
Issue is caused by webdriver waiting for the page to load.

```
        return wd.execute_script(
        f"var button=document.getElementsByClassName('elementclass');" +
        "button.click();" +
        "return button.className.includes('disabled');"
    )
```

Comment: This is not a good solution , you are triggering the click event using Jquery . It doesn't check whether the button is disabled or visible

Comment: We're just using normal javascript, no jquery. We know it will be visible. We have tests that test that. The issue is just whether the button became disabled. This works exactly how we need it. That's why I pointed to your solutions, because they will likely fit other people' solutions. The big issue is once we click the item using WebDriver it doesn't return to our Python code until AFTER the new page loads.

Comment: Once the button is disabled , run the command again you can see the script still passes

Comment: We verified this works by changing the class it checks for it, failed as it should. This all runs at once. We have a test to validate when it's still enabled and when its disabled :) Both pass. Since you answered with a perfectly valid answer and one I'd use, I'm awarding you the answer.

Comment: I meant this won't test whether clicking the button triggers a click event , you are skipping that part and directly triggering

Comment: oh, well the button becomes disabled from the click, the JS event is still triggered. Again, this is probably not something for everyone and you're solution is likely more reusable. We don't have complex event listeners, so triggering the click directly here was enough for us. All actions still function.